# Handling Resources Loading - dosen't work

Tags: dotnetbrowser

Method described here [enter link description here](http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/handling-resources-loading) dosen't work. The "ResourceHandler" is interface, so the "CanLoadResource" cant be overrided. Update the documentation and provide a correct way to handle resources loading

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for letting us know about a mistake in documentation.

Here is a proper `ResourceHandler` implementation:

```
private class TestResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
{
    public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Suppress ajax call - " + parameters.URL);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

A complete sample that demonstrates how to configure the resource handler can be found by the following link: [Filter AJAX calls via ResourceHandler](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110827-filtering-ajax-calls)

Comment: Ann, the problem is that the method "CanLoadResource" never fired

Comment: Thank you for letting us know about that. It appears that there is a ResourceHandler bug in DotNetBrowser 1.8.3. 

This bug can be workarounded by setting up a default network delegate:
`browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new DefaultNetworkDelegate();`


In addition, I recommend you to contact us via support e-mail.

Comment: The `ResourceHandler` issue is fixed in DotNetBrowser 1.8.4